# How to set individual NTFS partitions permissions behaviour for each user account?

Tags: 10.04, users, ntfs, guest-session

I have two NTFS partitions (**DOWNLOADS for downloaded files** and **VM for my VirtualBox .vdi file**) for which i must have full permissions for my allday use account. They should be also automounting when i login to this account.

But i've also set Guest account for guests. For Guest account, i want make **VM partition fully disabled and invisible (and thus it mustn't automount)** but **DOWNLOADS partition should be shared with limited privileges** with Guest account.

Editing *fstab* i'm able to share DOWNLOADS partition with Guest on limited privileges but VM can be only set to limited and have disabled automounting - so guest can't mount it but it still can be seen in Nautilus, plus I must always mount it manually when i login to allday account.

Is there some trick to make what i want?

Here's my *fstab* config:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=35e66658-5ee9-40cf-bf56-8204959e3df0 / xfs defaults 01
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=26c714cf-4236-45e7-9c46-cfcf91a215ae /home xfs defaults 02
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=1315BCB027C44639 /media/DOWNLOADS ntfs-3g auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,nodev,locale=pl_PL.utf8 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=60FF39EB72B72264 /media/VM ntfs noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0077,nodev,locale=pl_PL.utf8 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sda7 :
UUID=c52411f5-105c-45d1-971f-412f962c350e none swap sw 0 0
/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think i have solution, here it is:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1678406:

> *The second "0" in umask=0077 combined with uid=gid=1000 will do that.
>   Automounting has nothing to do with something being disabled or invisible. The last 2 "7" in umask=0077 will do what you want. Everyone will see that there is a /media/VM mountpount but only you will be able to open the folder.
>   Get rid of the "noauto" option.*

If someone know other solutions, post also, so we could preserve the diversity of solutions.  :)

Comment: I know u had to answer your own question, but, for completeness sake, post the solution here, not just the URL. Summarize the exact steps, parameters and settings required in your `fstab`.

Comment: @MestreLion Read carefully last post of that topic @ ubuntuforums.org, also with quoted post of Morbius1. And i recommend to read [Introduction to fstab @ Ubuntu Community Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). Cheers